# Kernel panic 0x00007f00

Tags: kernel

I tried to boot into my ubuntu machine and this error message appears. I read through dozens of previous questions about this and unfortunately no one answered with an objective step by step on how to solve the problem and boot to the system.

Edit: I was able to solve my problem reinstalling the OS without erasing data, by not setting the "format" flag in the ubuntu live usb. It doesn't get to the root of the problem, but solves the issue of how to gain access to the system and the data once again.

Comment: No! The only answer does not propose any solution!

Comment: I would boot a *live* system & checkout your hardware (`smartctl` etc) then `fsck` (file system check) your ssd/hdd. If errors are detected on the *fs* and fixed, you'll likely find it boots normally next time.

Comment: Fsck immediately returns this:

fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/sda5: clean, 895897/64462848 files, 21272980/257846784 blocks

Comment: The hardware is fine!

Comment: What OS & release are you talking about?

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS.